# Eclipse: how to open files always in the active edtor?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible in Eclipse to open files (from Project Explorer) always in the active editor? (The same way, as Qt Creator does with *views*).

When I'm trying to open the file which is already opened in the inactive editor, Eclipse just changes the editor to inactive. I'd like to open *'another'* tab of the file in the active view, without changing the editor.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Window>New Editor or right click on editor's tab and select 'New Editor'.

Comment: Thanks, but can I get it 'automatically', when I open the file which is already opened?

Comment: I couldn't find any preference to do that. I think the possibility to open another editor on the same source was added only from eclipse 3, (it is a nice feature but maybe statistically not used that often (I myself use it quite rarely)) so probably that is the reason why there is no preference to set it up this way.